# Assertion writing without clock for async reset

Tags: system-verilog-assertions

I have two resets in my design. Reset_a and Reset_b. both are asynchronous reset can come at any pint of time.
i have to write assertion to check if Reset_a is asserted Reset_b also assert at any point.
We don't have clock enable in this case.

can anyone help how to write assertion?

I have tried below code.

```
reset_assertion_check:
    assert property (@(posedge reset_a) $rose(reset_b) ##[*0:$] reset_b)
    else
      $error("reset error");
```

Comment: this will only work at `posedge reset_a` which probably happens only once in the simulation. Maybe something like `posedge reset_a or posedge reset_b`  is needed?

Comment: both are independent reset can come anytime once in the simulation but both the resets are not aligned to each other. Reset_a can come early and Reset_b some time later or vica versa.  There are no clocks running when reset is there.

Answer (score 0):

create dummy clock(any period) on test bench, then use the dummy clock to check Reset_a and Reset_b use assertion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).